# Connect SQL Server 2016 SSDT with TFS

Tags: sql-server, ssdt, sql-server-2016

I've just upgraded the SQL client tools on my PC to SQL Server 2016.

I no longer have a "Team" menu option in SSDT.

Under Tools > Options > Source control there is a drop down box for Source Control plug-in. But there are no options.

In my previous version SQL 2012 SSDT (VS 2010) I have the option of selecting "Visual Studio Team Foundation Server"

How do I get SSDT to connect to TFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The links and information are confusing but we did find a solution.

The short version is you need to install Visual Studio 2015. I used the free Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition. That includes the components needed to run Team Explorer.

Once we installed VS the Team menu is now visible in SQL Server 2016 SSDT. You can then add and configure TFS as before.

Comment: Please note though that the community edition  license will expire and ask to be renewed after about 30 days. :(

Comment: You could also use Express edition, which gets around the Community edition licensing restrictions. I ran into same issue and asked about it in the comments here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2015/07/21/licensing-and-packaging-changes-for-tfs-2015/

Answer (score 1):

[While the answer above](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/142006/97765) is true, it only applies to developers who are not employed by an enterprise or contributing to an open source project.  The EULA is pretty clear on this.  VS Pro is the only option today if you work for an Enterprise. Microsoft defines an Enterprise as any company with more than 100 employees and/or revenue above $1M/yr.

Comment: We have paid for SQL Server Enterprise, and that comes with SSDT which is VS2015. The only thing missing was the ability to connect to TFS. (Which we could do in the previous version). Why should I have to pay twice for the same product in order to use a compatibility feature with another MS product we have also paid for?